# Selecting the records with corresponding string separately within JSON

Tags: python, json

Want to select `BBBBB@4##` , `AAAAA@5##` , `AAAAA@6##` separately

**JSON**

```
x = {'d': 'BBBBB@4##{"pp-0": "1000", "pp-1": "1001", "pp-2": "1002", "pp-3": "1003", "pp-4": "1004", "pp-5": "1005", "pp-6": "1006", "pp-7": "1007", "pp-8": "1008", "pp-9": "1009", "pp-10": "1010", "pp-11": "1011", "pp-12": "1012", "pp-13": "1013", "pp-14": "1014", "pp-17": "1015", "pp-27": "1016"}AAAAA@5##{"pp-0": "1000", "pp-1": "1001", "pp-2": "1002", "pp-3": "1003", "pp-4": "1004", "pp-5": "1005", "pp-6": "1006", "pp-7": "1007", "pp-8": "1008", "pp-9": "1009", "pp-10": "1010", "pp-11": "1011", "pp-12": "1012", "pp-13": "1013", "pp-14": "1014", "pp-17": "1015", "pp-27": "1016"}AAAAA@6##{"pp-0": "1000", "pp-1": "1001", "pp-2": "1002", "pp-3": "1003", "pp-4": "1004", "pp-5": "1005", "pp-6": "1006", "pp-7": "1007", "pp-8": "1008", "pp-9": "1009", "pp-10": "1010", "pp-11": "1011", "pp-12": "1012", "pp-13": "1013", "pp-14": "1014", "pp-17": "1015", "pp-27": "1016"}'}
```

**Python Code**

```
x['d']['AAAAA@5##']
```

**Expected Selected Result**

```
{"pp-0": "1000", "pp-1": "1001", "pp-2": "1002", "pp-3": "1003", "pp-4": "1004", "pp-5": "1005", "pp-6": "1006", "pp-7": "1007", "pp-8": "1008", "pp-9": "1009", "pp-10": "1010", "pp-11": "1011", "pp-12": "1012", "pp-13": "1013", "pp-14": "1014", "pp-17": "1015", "pp-27": "1016"}
```

Comment: But that's a string?

Comment: Youd dict `x` has only **ONE** pair, with key `'d'` and a very long value

Comment: dear, yes, and the value/string in json/dictionary format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest a simple regex to extract each `AAAA@X##{...}` block and use them to build a new dictionary

```
import json
import re

x = {'d': 'AAAAA@4##{"pp-0": "1000", "pp-1": "1001", "pp-2": "1002", "pp-3": "1003", "pp-4": "1004", '
          '"pp-5": "1005", "pp-6": "1006", "pp-7": "1007", "pp-8": "1008", "pp-9": "1009", "pp-10": "1010", '
          '"pp-11": "1011", "pp-12": "1012", "pp-13": "1013", "pp-14": "1014", "pp-17": "1015", "pp-27": "1016"}'
          'AAAAA@5##{"pp-0": "1000", "pp-1": "1001", "pp-2": "1002", "pp-3": "1003", "pp-4": "1004", '
          '"pp-5": "1005", "pp-6": "1006", "pp-7": "1007", "pp-8": "1008", "pp-9": "1009", "pp-10": "1010", '
          '"pp-11": "1011", "pp-12": "1012", "pp-13": "1013", "pp-14": "1014", "pp-17": "1015", "pp-27": "1016"}'
          'AAAAA@6##{"pp-0": "1000", "pp-1": "1001", "pp-2": "1002", "pp-3": "1003", "pp-4": "1004", '
          '"pp-5": "1005", "pp-6": "1006", "pp-7": "1007", "pp-8": "1008", "pp-9": "1009", "pp-10": "1010", '
          '"pp-11": "1011", "pp-12": "1012", "pp-13": "1013", "pp-14": "1014", "pp-17": "1015", "pp-27": "1016"}'}

result = {}
for key, val in re.findall(r"(AAAAA@\d+##)({.*?})", x['d']):
    result[key] = json.loads(val)

print(result.keys())  # dict_keys(['AAAAA@4##', 'AAAAA@5##', 'AAAAA@6##'])
print(result['AAAAA@4##'])  # {'pp-0': '1000', ...  'pp-27': '1016'}
```

---

If the identifier can be another form, change the regex, here's few examples

- `([A-Z]{5}@\d+##)` : 5 uppercase letters instead of 5 A
- `([A-Za-z]{2,5}@\d+##)` : 2 to 5 letters instead of 5 A

Comment: dear, how about the first records is difference with other like BBBBB@4## ?

Comment: @Mary Just adapt the regex, I can't know the variety of identifier you can have, see my edit

Comment: dear, how about if i want to delete the last character " } " for my case i want to delete this with every values from  "pp-27": "1016"} to  "pp-27": "1016"

Comment: @Mary You already have a strange format that need to be parsed with regex, why complicate it more ? Where do you get that format ? Couldn't the code that make it, make it DIRECTLY parsable nicely ?

Comment: Dear, since my case have some special character at the end, i need to remove it, not applied for this situation

Comment: @Mary I can't help more, if you remove the important data, that solution doesn't effectivly apply anymore

Answer (score 1):

The value under the key 'd' is a string and not even a valid json.

The right answer is to fix the data format before trying using it.

... but if you couldn't you'll have to try to convert it to a valid json like this (**which is far from beeing bullet proof**):

```
>>> x['d'] = json.loads('{"' + x['d'].replace('##{', '##": {').replace('}A','}, "') + "}")
>>> x['d']['AAAA@5##']
{'pp-0': '1000', 'pp-1': '1001', 'pp-2': '1002', 'pp-3': '1003', 'pp-4': '1004', 'pp-5': '1005', 'pp-6': '1006', 'pp-7': '1007', 'pp-8': '1008', 'pp-9': '1009', 'pp-10': '1010', 'pp-11': '1011', 'pp-12': '1012', 'pp-13': '1013', 'pp-14': '1014', 'pp-17': '1015', 'pp-27': '1016'}
```

Comment: dear, how about the first records is difference with other like BBBBB@4## ?

Comment: well if there are more constraints this hack is not suitable anymore. You should fix the data before receiving it like you show it.